# AsyncTaskloader relation with fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-context, loader

-Do I have to use fragment activity(or any activity) to use the [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)? And do I have also to implement `LoaderManger`?

-I success with asyncTask to use it outside the mainActivity and handle the returned data with interface.Can I do the same with asynctaskloader?

-why the constructor need a context ?what context value if i execute this thread outside an activity?

```
      new AsyncTaskLoader<Service.DataHandler>(****){
               //**** here in the place of context , what i shoud put?
                DataHandler mHaDataHandler;

                @Override
                public DataHandler loadInBackground() {
                            String getUrl = url;
                            byte []  GetResult = newservice.doGet(requestIdentifier, getUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }

                return mHaDataHandler;
            }
            @Override
            public void deliverResult(DataHandler data) {
                super.deliverResult(data);
                //here handlig the response
                ServiceListener.onServiceInterface(requestIdentifier, mHaDataHandler.getData());

            }

        };
//...... the rest of the code , my point in the constructor , it applies to context , what i should put in this place
```

it would be great for examples but without fragment Activity or any activity

Comment: did u try anything ?

Comment: i want to know in the constructor , what i should put if it wont be in an activity

Comment: check the example given here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html. it has AsyncTaskLoader being called from listfragment

Comment: thanks , i saw it , but i dont want to use it in this method , i want to call a normal function not from activity or list fragment and the result handle it in another class .so the context if there is a solution to do it like this ?

Comment: most of examples using list fragment or activity or fragment activity , i didnt find any exmaple without these ? so if it possible to do it without (fragment activity, fragment list , activity) ?